# printer samsung ml 1670 driverproblem and missing rastertosplc

Tags: drivers, printing

I'm not that experienced in solving problems myself when it comes to Ubuntu, and i am not really experienced using the Terminal.

My problem is that a few days ago i reinstalled ubuntu 13.10 and updated it to 14.04. Since then I haven't been able to use my laserprinter `(Samsung ML 1670)`. Thanks to other threads with similar problems i can get so far that just the `rastertosplc` seems to be missing. And thats about it.

Is there anyone who knows what I should do now?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was already answer before (search for rastertosplc). I already solve the same problem I had with the same printer you mention.

Here a copy of the answer:
--There exist a symbolic link called rastertospl (note the missing 'c') in that directory (in my case /usr/lib/cups/filter). If you move to the directory in your terminal and execute "sudo ln -s rastertospl rastertosplc" everything should be fine (it got my Samsung ML 1675 to print immediately).--